Applying a Tilt in 3D curves along path w/multiple control points
Is it possible to apply a spiraled tilt to a complete path?  The control points mess up the flow.

You can move a spiral onto the input curve, there's just one problem if that input curve is cyclic: spiral settings don't allow creating cyclic spirals, and so when you set an integer number of rotations on your spiral, the ending point is at the same angle as the starting point. This is why you can use a 0-height spiral to make a circle with doubled start/end point. However you don't want that for a cyclic spline, where the last segment is implied (from end to start) - this is why I remove the last point.



